# logging exception in try-catch statement

Tags: php, exception, logging, try-catch

So I have a code like this:

```
    for($x=1;$x<=3;$x++)
    {   
        try
        {
            $c = new client($user_id, $ident);
            log("Client initialized successfully...");
            break;
        }
        catch (Exception $e)
        {
            log("Error in attempt($x)to init client");
        }
    }
```

My question is, is there any possibility that an exception can be thrown after the line `log("Client initialized successfully...");`? Because if yes, then it will mean that the log will have both success and error messages for the initialization process. Technically the exception should only rise when the new client object is initialized, but I am not certain...

Comment: I think what you want is `error_log()`, not `log()`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, yes it can if function log throws an exception, and also if I were you I would rename the function name, because there is a function log already:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.log.php

Answer (score 0):

It is only possible if the log function throws an exception.

Alternatively, you could have a `$success` variable that is initialized to `true`.  You set it to `false` in the `catch`.  Then check it after the entire try/catch block.

Answer (score 0):

Exception can only be thrown here in lines:

```
$c = new client($user_id, $ident);
```

or

```
log("Client initialized successfully...");
```

( we don't know what function log does).

It's quite strange, that you try in loop initialize object 3 times - do you expect many errors here?